# tabnavigator inside stacknavigator

Tags: react-native, tabnavigator, stack-navigator

```
const Stylelist = StackNavigator({
  Login: {
    screen: LoginScreen,
    navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
      header: null,
    }),
  },
  Register: {
    screen: RegisterScreen,
    navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
      header: null,
    }),
  },
  Home: {
    screen: HomeScreen,
    navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
      title: 'Home',
    }),
  },
  Profile: {
    screen: TabNavigator({
      Profile: {
        screen: ProfileScreen,
        navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
          title: 'Profile',
        }),
      },
      Friends: {
        screen: FriendsScreen,
        navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
          title: 'My Friends',
        }),
      },
    }),
    navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
      title: 'Home',
    }),
  },
  ProfileDetail: {
    screen: ProfileDetailScreen,
    navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
      title: 'Profile Detail',
    }),
  },
});
```

what if I want to navigate to ProfileDetailScreen from ProfileScreen? lets say I have touchableOpacity inside ProfileScreen that i want to navigate to ProfileDetailScreen

thanks

Update : I managed to use StackNavigator inside TabNavigator with headerMode None on StackNavigator inside TabNavigator, its feel the same at the first time, but if you go back from ProfileDetailScreen, it's back to HomeScreen (because back button is from StackNavigator in first line)

Answer (score 0):

You can navigate to ProfileScreen like this : this.props.navigation.navigate("Profile").
"Profile" is key for StackNavigator's page definition. Detailed information [here](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigating.html)

Also i suggest to use latest [react navigation (v2)](https://reactnavigation.org)

Comment: i know to use this.props.navigation.navigate("Profile"), but you cant do that because if you declare Profile on parent, the sub child cant get that. i hope you know what i mean